Is There a Difference in Meaning Between "As" and "While" in the Past Continuous?
Is there a difference in meaning when using "as" and "while" in the Past Continuous? Do they mean the same thing in terms of emphasizing "duration".
Here are some examples:
The phone rang while we were cooking dinner.
As we were cooking dinner, the phone rang.
My spouse came home while I was putting our son to bed.
My spouse came home as I was putting our son to bed.

Yes. The only detail to note is that as has other meanings such as because, so you need to watch out for potential confusion. But in your examples, no difference. (I assume you meant As we were cooking dinner... in the second sentence, and that would also mean the same.)

The answers to this question note that "as" is more suitable with a moment in time, while either can be used with an interval of time ("as I arrived" not "while I arrived", but either "as I was cooking" or "while I was cooking"). There are also other cases when one or the other is more suitable - search here for as while.

I find this questions particularly interesting for German learners of English, as there is the German word "als", which is used like "as" as in "As an expert, you will know that..." but also in "als ich drei war" ("when I was three years old"). Many non-native English teachers in Germany (including me) encourage students to use "when" rather than "as".

There's a very subtle difference between as and while, but it's not enough to cause a difference in meaning between the two. Your examples both mean the same thing.
The difference is that while typically refers to a period of time, and as typically refers to a moment in time. For example:

While I was cooking, I was also playing a video game.

This refers to an extended period of time between when I started cooking and when I finished. It could have lasted the entire time I was cooking or some portion of that time.

As I was cooking, the phone rang.

This refers to a single moment in time, not an extended period. But that single moment happened between the time I started cooking and the time I finished.
